# What is the correct encoding of a Boolean value in a SOAP message?

Tags: .net, soap

We have produced a web service in VB.NET against a WSDL file provided to us by our client.

In testing, our client has raised an issue complaining that the XML produced by our web service uses 'true' and 'false' for boolean values, not '1' and '0'.  Furthermore, they are suggesting that our implementation is 'broken' because of this.

I was under the impression that 'true/false' and '1/0' in this context were interchangeable?

Either way, all of the XML serialisation is being handled by the .NET framework, not our code - so I assume I have little chance of changing it anyway?!

Can anyone point me to some documentation which either backs up my story or proves me wrong? If I am wrong, does anyone know how I might be able to alter this behaviour?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [SOAP spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part1-20070427/): 'the boolean lexical forms "1" and "true" are interchangeable.'

Not much more to say, really.

Answer (score 5):

Not WSDL- related but XML-related: a customer once claimed they could not read our XML files and insisted that we would generate XML files according to the standard. Unfortunately, their standard was different from the official standard. For example, they could not parse comments, had troubles with the XML header and they expected the XML to be nicely indented with linebreaks after every element. Why? Because they wrote their own XML parser, that was unable to follow the true standard.
Since our software is also used by other clients, we first wanted to send them "The Finger" and just let them disappear quietly. But one person from marketing found a nicer solution and one of our developers was sent to this client to give additional advise about the correct usage of XML. We educated the client, who suddenly realized that they didn't have to write their own parser. We helped them to improve their own code base and made them quite happy since we solved the problem by educating them. And all this for a small, additional fee so marketing was happy too. :-)
There is an alternative, though! Replace booleans with your own enumerations. For example yes/no or something similar. The advantage is that you can then expand those enumerations with additional values like yes/no/maybe or even [yes/no/filenotfound](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx)...
Still, booleans are often preferred and to keep the SOAP messages human-readable, you better use true/false since people tend to make mistakes when you use 1/0. Why? Simple, 1 is true? Or False? In some programming languages, -1 means true. And in older languages, 1 meant false. (Because in those languages, a boolean was a kind of error-bit, which -if set- equals 1 thus indicates an error.)
Readability should therefor mean that you should prefer to use true/false or else end up discussing why 1 means true...

Comment: Thanks for your response. Normally I'd be all for your marketing guy's approach, but in this instance I fear I'm too far down the food-chain to be heard!

Comment: As for changing to an enumeration - that's a good idea, except that I have to conform to a published WSDL. I'll struggle on down the political route and see where I get! :o)

Answer (score 2):

Your choices are:

1. Tell the client that you're right (which you are) and that `true` and `false` are perfectly valid boolean values in SOAP.  And then deal with an angry client.
2. Change your boolean properties to ints.

I'd go with #2, myself, just for the harmony of it all.

Comment: I would go with option 1, else other clients might complain about expecting true/false and receiving 0/1 instead. To make matters worse, without looking up: does 1 mean true, or false? :-)

Comment: Well, 1 means true, but in VB.Net I think -1 is true, so your point is well taken.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I have to conform with a published WSDL, so #2 is out. It's looking increasingly like #1 is the way I'm going to go!